# Conda package build error

Tags: python, build, jinja2, conda

I'm trying to build a package and host it on anaconda, but I cannot successfully build the package and it is giving me an error that I don't know how to solve.

This is the package's `meta.yaml` contents:

```
package:
  name: dbcollection
  version: 0.1.5

source:
  git_url: https://github.com/farrajota/dbcollection.git
  git_rev: 0.1.5

requirements:
  build:
    - python
    - setuptools
    - h5py
    - numpy
    - patool
    - progressbar2
    - pytest
    - scipy
    - xmltodict
    - requests
    - pillow

  run:
    - python
    - h5py
    - numpy
    - patool
    - progressbar2
    - pytest
    - scipy
    - xmltodict
    - requests
    - pillow

test:
  imports:
    - dbcollection

about:
  home: https://github.com/farrajota/dbcollection
  license: MIT
```

And this is the error message I get when building the package using `conda build <recipe_path>`:

```
Packaging dbcollection-0.1.5-py35h1c746c7_0
INFO:conda_build.build:Packaging dbcollection-0.1.5-py35h1c746c7_0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mf/anaconda3/bin/conda-build", line 6, in <module>
    sys.exit(conda_build.cli.main_build.main())
  File "/home/mf/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda_build/cli/main_build.py", line 340, in main
    execute(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/mf/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda_build/cli/main_build.py", line 331, in execute
    noverify=args.no_verify)
  File "/home/mf/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda_build/api.py", line 183, in build
    need_source_download=need_source_download, config=config, variants=variants)
  File "/home/mf/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 1615, in build_tree
    built_packages=built_packages,
  File "/home/mf/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 1184, in build
    built_package = bundlers[output_d.get('type', 'conda')](output_d, m, env)
  File "/home/mf/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 706, in bundle_conda
    files = post_process_files(metadata, initial_files)
  File "/home/mf/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 621, in post_process_files
    get_build_metadata(m)
  File "/home/mf/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda_build/post.py", line 522, in get_build_metadata
    raise ValueError("support for __conda_version__ has been removed as of Conda-build 3.0."
ValueError: support for __conda_version__ has been removed as of Conda-build 3.0.Try Jinja templates instead: http://conda.pydata.org/docs/building/meta-yaml.html#templating-with-jinja
```

Here is the [full build log output](https://gist.github.com/farrajota/9d41eb17052c642d928d9e24b5caf4d3) message.

What might be the cause of this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've fixed this by switching some fields in my `meta.yaml` file.

```
package:
  name: dbcollection
  version: {{ GIT_DESCRIBE_TAG }}

source:
  path: ../

build:
  number: {{ GIT_DESCRIBE_NUMBER|int }}

requirements:
  build:
    - python
    - setuptools
    - h5py
    - numpy
    - patool
    - progressbar2
    - pytest
    - scipy
    - xmltodict
    - requests
    - pillow

  run:
    - python
    - h5py
    - numpy
    - patool
    - progressbar2
    - pytest
    - scipy
    - xmltodict
    - requests
    - pillow

test:
  imports:
    - dbcollection

about:
  home: https://github.com/farrajota/dbcollection
  license: MIT
```

I've tried several combinations of jinja2 templates in the `source` section, but I think the `path=../` was the real solution for my problem. Now its building properly.